# Hide Material-UI Autocomplete popup until text is typed

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a working Material-UI `Autocomplete` implemented, however currently when you click to select an item it displays a clickable dropdown list of all items in addition to the text search.

I would like it so no dropdown options are shown until something is typed first.

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box"
  options={listofitems}
  value={itemid}
  onChange={viewitemlist}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params}
    label="Item Id"
    variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can control the [`open`](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/#:%7E:text=of%20the%20callback.-,open,-bool) state and tell the `Autocomplete` to open the popup only after the user typed something.

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

return (
  <Autocomplete
    open={open}
    onInputChange={(_, value) => {
      if (value.length === 0) {
        if (open) setOpen(false);
      } else {
        if (!open) setOpen(true);
      }
    }}
    onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
    {...}
  />
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: So I noticed when text is typed the popup shows, but then when the text is cleared the popup still shows

Comment: So while this does work it does not seem possible to have it set such that the popup only shows while text is entered and not when it is empty

Comment: @OnePiece Updated my answer

Comment: Its frustrating that your solution is so simple and logical but I could not think of it myself even when looking at the docs.