# Autocomplete component keeps menu open when prefilling value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the [MUI Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) component for my React application. I want to prefill an existing value from some user state if present. However, when I do so, the value is prefilled but the menu remains open (shown in the picture below with the "No options" message)

I've tried controlling the `open` attribute and setting it to false but the menu remains open. I've tried using a `ref` on the component and blurring it out but the menu still remains open. I've also tried setting the `defaultValue` instead of `value` but the menu still remains open.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: getPrefillValue]

```
export const MyAutocomplete(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null)
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

    // Prefill value
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.value) {
            const selectedOption = props.options.find(option => option.id === props.value.id)
            if (selectedOption) {
                setValue(selectedOption)
                setOpen(false) // Tried closing the menu here but this doesn't work
            }
        }
    }, [])

    const handleInputChange = (e, newValue) => {
        if (newValue.length > 1) {
            setOpen(true)
        } else {
            setOpen(false)
        }
    }

    const onChange = (e, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue)
    }

    ...otherFunctionsRedacted

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            value={value}
            open={open}
            onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
            onInputChange={handleInputChange}
            onChange={onChange}
            options={props.options}
            ...otherPropsHere
        />
    )
}
```

**Edit**:

I think my issue is with the `onInputChange`. I only want the menu to appear after the user starts typing a few characters, hence my use of the `onInputChange` property.
[Hide Material-UI Autocomplete popup until text is typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69380819/hide-material-ui-autocomplete-popup-until-text-is-typed)

However, when prefilling a value, `onInputChange` is being called which sees that the length of the value is sufficiently long and opens the menu but the corresponding `onClose` is not called. I was able to put together a reproducible example below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-examples-forked-71rgk5?file=/demo.tsx

You can tell that upon first loading the component, a value is prefilled but the whole menu is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question: does your implementation require full control of the Autocomplete component?

While it is possible to control the behavior of `Autocomplete` such as manually setting the `value` and `open` properties while also manually handling `onChange`, `Autocomplete` can take care of simple, straight-forward implementations.

For example, using an uncontrolled `Autocomplete` component (a component that does not have the `value` property defined), you can use the `defaultValue` prop to initialize the value.  You then pull the selected value out with `onChange`.

```
<Autocomplete
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  defaultValue={props.selectedValue ?? null}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Uncontrolled" />}
  onChange={(_e, newValue) => {
    console.log("Uncontrolled Value:", newValue)
  }}
/>
```

Alternatively, you can control the `Autocomplete` and set it via state/props.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedValue ?? null)

<Autocomplete
  value={value}
  onChange={(_e, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue)
    console.log("Controlled Value:", newValue)
  }}
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controlled" />}
/>
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-examples-q7crw7?file=/demo.tsx:615-963)

Either way, these should behave like you would expect and not open the options table when you set a default/pre-selected value.

If you want to keep your implementation, perhaps look at setting the `autoSelect` propery to `true`.  Does that close the table when you apply a pre-selected value?

---

Ok.  I think I have it now.  Reading back through old GitHub issues, it appears that MUI used to have a `startAfter` property that would enable exactly what you are trying to do, but for some reason they removed the feature. [Initial Issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/19591) / [Removal of Feature](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/20551)

With a little work, I figured out a way to emulate the behavior:

```
const handleInputChange = (e, newValue) => {
  if (
    newValue.length > 2 
    && !top100Films.map((film) => film.title).includes(newValue)
  ) {
    setOpen(true)
  } else {
    setOpen(false)
  }
}

const handleFocus = () => {
 if (
    value &&
    (value > 2 || top100Films.map((film) => film.title).includes(value.title))
  ) {
    setOpen(true)
  }
}

return (
  <Autocomplete
    value={value}
    open={open}
    onFocus={handleFocus}
    onBlur={() => setOpen(false)}
    onInputChange={handleInputChange}
    onChange={(_e, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue)
    }}
    options={top100Films}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controlled" />}
  />
)
```

Since you are controlling the `open` property, you will need to account for all conditions of opening.  The `onFocus` and `onBlur` properties should give you the access to do that.  I think the above code gets it to behave like you would like it to.

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-examples-forked-o8tt3i?file=/demo.jsx)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! As I understand, I need it to be controlled in order to handle the opening and closing of the menu when the user types a certain number of characters. Because of your great insights and sandbox example, I was able to edit it to show what is happening. I've added an edit to the bottom of my original post to give more detail.

Comment: I had a response to your comment, but I was thinking about it and the response would not work.  Let me think a bit more.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I happened to glimpse your suggested edit and I'm curious: why wouldn't it have worked?

Comment: The previous edit would not have opened a new dropdown any time a option was selected.  No bueno.